# Delphi XE doesn't consume a WebService correctly

Tags: xml, delphi, soap, biztalk, delphi-xe

Having the WSDL show below Delphi XE is creating the code as show here. Out WebService is running on a BizTalk server:

```
....
....

  PicassoBTSTest_PortalOrchestration_Port_Portal = interface(IInvokable)
  ['{706CEB1F-0EC1-08C2-03C7-395C12905558}']
    **procedure Operation_Portal(var part: Variant); stdcall;**
  end;

function GetPicassoBTSTest_PortalOrchestration_Port_Portal(UseWSDL: Boolean=System.False; Addr: string=''; HTTPRIO: THTTPRIO = nil): PicassoBTSTest_PortalOrchestration_Port_Portal;

....
....
```

When calling the WebService I'm doing as shown here:

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  X: PicassoBTSTest_PortalOrchestration_Port_Portal;
  V: Variant;
begin
  X := GetPicassoBTSTest_PortalOrchestration_Port_Portal;

  V := 'JUST A TEST';

  X.Operation_Portal(V);
  ShowMessage(V);
end;
```

As we can see in our logs this code is calling our back end correct. But we do not receive the correct response back. The V parameter is unchanged after we call the Operation_Portal. It contains the 'JUST A TEST' text when it should contain an other values.

I've tried running the code from Delphi 2006 and it gives me the same result.

What am I doing wrong. Why doesn't I receive the response from our back end?

/Brian

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
-<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex" xmlns:wsa10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/policy" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:tns="http://techotel.dk/" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="http://techotel.dk/" name="BizTalkServiceInstance">-<wsdl:documentation><CreationInfo Created="2012-01-26 10:31:43Z"/></wsdl:documentation>-<wsdl:types><xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://techotel.dk/Imports"/></wsdl:types>-<wsdl:message name="PicassoBTSTest_PortalOrchestration_Port_Portal_Operation_Portal_InputMessage"><wsdl:part name="part" type="xsd:anyType"/></wsdl:message>-<wsdl:message name="PicassoBTSTest_PortalOrchestration_Port_Portal_Operation_Portal_OutputMessage"><wsdl:part name="part" type="xsd:anyType"/></wsdl:message>-<wsdl:portType name="PicassoBTSTest_PortalOrchestration_Port_Portal"><wsdl:documentation>service "PicassoBTSTest.PortalOrchestration" port "Port_Portal"</wsdl:documentation>-<wsdl:operation name="Operation_Portal"><wsdl:documentation>operation "Operation_Portal"</wsdl:documentation><wsdl:input message="tns:PicassoBTSTest_PortalOrchestration_Port_Portal_Operation_Portal_InputMessage"/><wsdl:output message="tns:PicassoBTSTest_PortalOrchestration_Port_Portal_Operation_Portal_OutputMessage"/></wsdl:operation></wsdl:portType>-<wsdl:binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ITwoWayAsync" type="tns:PicassoBTSTest_PortalOrchestration_Port_Portal"><soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>-<wsdl:operation name="Operation_Portal"><wsdl:documentation>operation "Operation_Portal"</wsdl:documentation><soap:operation style="document" soapAction="Operation_Portal"/>-<wsdl:input><soap:body use="literal"/></wsdl:input>-<wsdl:output><soap:body use="literal"/></wsdl:output></wsdl:operation></wsdl:binding>-<wsdl:service name="BizTalkServiceInstance">-<wsdl:port name="BasicHttpBinding_ITwoWayAsync" binding="tns:BasicHttpBinding_ITwoWayAsync"><soap:address location="http://akibiztalk01.internal.local/PicassoBTSTestPortal/PicassoBTSTest_PortalOrchestration_Port_Portal.svc"/></wsdl:port></wsdl:service></wsdl:definitions>
```

Comment: How does the response XML look like?

Comment: The response should look like this below (I don't know how to make it readable?).


<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Body>
      <OTA_HotelInvCountNotifRS TimeStamp="2009-07-01T11:27:04" Version="4" xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
         <Success/>
      </OTA_HotelInvCountNotifRS>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>

Comment: You can edit your question to add the expected and the **actual** response XML, which can be intercepted on the Delphi side or using a HTTP sniffer like Fiddler

Comment: In your response example, I see no element which contains the expected return value. Only a Success indicator, but no element with a value for the (var) part parameter.

Comment: The complete XML of the response posted should be what I would expect in the value for the (var) part parameter.

Comment: The HTTPRio component has an OnAfterExecute handler, which can be used to capture the actual server response content (and save it to a file for example)

Answer (score 0):

First I would verify that the server sends a XML SOAP response back which contains the expected value.

If the value is in the response, then Delphi somehow fails to assign it to the Variant variable.

Has the service been developed in C#? Maybe for tests it is helpful to write a Delphi version of the service and compare the response XML structure.

Comment: I don't know exactly how it's written. I would assume that it is written in C# as it is BizTalk. I can't say for sure as the guy responsible for this is not at work today.

Another issue this is that when I apply the method call with XML in the parameter Delphi Escapes some characters. The character < becomes &lt; and > becomes &gt; I need to be able to send clean XML.

Comment: I've just talked to the developer of the WebService. He'll create a Client developed in C#. Thanks for the input.